# Running time of algorithm with many for loops

Tags: matrices, asymptotics

I've an algorithm:
(a1,...,an)(b1,...,bn)(c1,...,cn)
x <- 0
for i <- 1 to n do
   for j <- 1 to n do
      for k <- 1 to n do
         x <- x + (ai * bj * ck^2)
return x

So considering there are 3 for loops that would so far make the running time O(n^3) right? But for the final loop the statement points to different spots in each of the arrays, i j and k (not sure if this actually makes any difference). And furthermore there is a square within the final loop, and I've seen things about squares within the loops multiplying the polynomial a fair bit, leading me to think the run time is O(n^5) as I'm assuming it would be n^3 * n^2?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more suited for stackoverflow programming forum.

Three loops make it O(n^3).
Arrays are made so that access is O(1) => constant doesn't depend on n.
Multiplication is also O(1).

So the final run time complexity is O(n^3).